# PHP - file get contents not working when passing URL from database otherwise works fine

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents, scrape

I am trying to get contents of a web page using file_get_contents

**Scenario One:**
When I pass a single URL directly from a text field it works perfect.

**Scenario Two:**
When I take multiple URLs in a text area and then store them in a Mysql database. Then I run a for loop to pass the URL to the same code snippet as in scenario 1 it returns this error

```
Warning: file_get_contents( URL ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\wamp\www\scrape\urltoscrape.php on line 13
```

I felt that the prob was with the datatype being used. So it was initially varchar I changed it to text.

I also tried strip space. When I echo the URL out it prints it as is with no additional characters or spaces.

Also since it is in a loop I do not think the issue is with multiple URLs being passed at a time. All the URLs individually work fine when tried through scenario 1.

Please help. I am at my wits end.

Comment: I have researched the issue and have not found anything that comes close. I KNOW how to use file_get_contents().As I said the script is working fine with single url from form and I am passing $URL .... **What I am looking for assistance with is why it wouldn't work after the URL is saved in database and then sent to the same function.**

Answer (score 1):

> `file_get_contents( URL )`

This error tells you, it is trying to open the URL `"URL"`. Make sure you did not forget a `$` before the variable name.

Comment: Hi ... Thanks for the input. As I said the script is working fine with single url from form and I am passing $URL .... What I am looking for assistance with is why it wouldn't work after the URL is saved in database and then sent to the same function.

Comment: @Srisaas: show us your code! There is something you do not tell us. And the PHP error clearly says you are trying to open the URL "URL" – maybe there's an error storing/retrieving the value from the db …

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() expects a string which it has to follow. Now if you write url as its argument, it will try to fetch the contents of URL

try

```
file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Hi ... Thanks for the input. As I said the script is working fine with single url from form and I am passing $URL .... What I am looking for assistance with is why it wouldn't work after the URL is saved in database and then sent to the same function.

Comment: Problem resolved. Thanks everyone. Issue was with parsing the URLs from the text area. 

Cheers!